# Finding the Moment Generating Function of X + Y

Tags: probability, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

X is a poisson random variable with parameter Y, and Y itself is a poisson Random variable with parameter $\lambda$ how can I find the moment generating function of X + Y.

At first I tried to find the distribution of X using the law of total probability, but I couldn't calculate the series and got stuck.

the series I tried to calculate

$\sum_{b=0}^{\infty} P(X = a| Y = b) P(Y = b) = \frac{b^a e^{-b}}{a!} \cdot \frac{\lambda^{b}e^{-\lambda}}{b!}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the law of total expectation (tower rule) and the fact that the MGF of a poisson distribution with mean $\mu$ is $t \mapsto e^{\mu (e^t-1)}$,

\begin{align}
E[e^{t(X+Y)}]
&= E[E[e^{t(X+Y)} \mid Y]]
\\
&= E[e^{tY} E[e^{tX} \mid Y]]
\\
&= E[e^{tY} e^{Y(e^t - 1)}].
\end{align}
Combine the two terms and apply the MGF of $Y$ to finish.